# Проблема с выбором системного JRE

Tags: java, java-8, установка, реестр, path

Всем привет!

Установил себе комплект разработчика на языке программирования Java под версией 14.0.1 (JDK 14), изначально корректно настроил системные переменные среды, чтобы система могла распозновать JRE и я мог использовать последнюю версию компилятора Javac. Прописал переменную JAVA_HOME, добавил новое значение для системнной переменной Path и вроде бы всё было хорошо. Было хорошо, пока не установил JDK 1.8, после чего начались определённые проблемы. Вместе с ним установилась контрольная панель Java (Java Control Panel), где в разделе, который посвящён JRE, было установлено значение 1.8 во вкладке «System». Причём что-то поменять не представляется возможным, так как кнопки «Find», «Add» и «Remove» не являются активными. Когда в командной строке прописиваю команду: `java -version`, то выдаётся следующий результат:

```
java version "1.8.0_241"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_241-b07)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.241-b07, mixed mode)
```

Поискал информацию в глобальной сети, но ничего толкового не нашёл. Думал, что поможет редактирование реестра, но после попытки его отредактировать получаю следующее.

```
Error: Registry key 'Software\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment'\CurrentVersion'
has value '14', but '1.8' is required.
Error: could not find java.dll
Error: Could not find Java SE Runtime Environment.
```

И это несмотря на то, что все пути были прописаны корректно. Ранее выдавалась версия 14, когда вводил эту команду. В чём может быть проблема и что необходимо поменять? С таким уже сталкивался ранее, когда пользовался версией 11 и установил себе 1.8 для совместимости с некоторыми программами. Столкнулся с тем же и помогло только полное удаление дистрибутива с 8-мой версией JDK. Но это не самое лучшее решение, так как хотелось бы иметь несколько версий JRE на машине, так как в этом имеется реальная необходимость. Прошу помочь с этим вопросом[image: ![введите сюда описание изображения]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DTuC2.jpg)

Comment: какой путь у вас в java_home и path сейчас для jre?

Comment: Сейчас Вам всё напишу.

Comment: Системные переменные: JAVA_HOME: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14.0.1

Comment: Path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14.0.1\bin

Comment: Устанавливал только для JDK, для JRE ничего отдельно не выставлял.

Comment: а JRE_HOME куда указывает?

Comment: Такой переменной у меня вообще нет. Указать её? И если указывать то, куда именно? На C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14.0.1 или на C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14.0.1\bin ?

Comment: https://www.jamf.com/jamf-nation/articles/348/configuring-the-java_home-and-jre_home-environment-variables-on-a-windows-server

Comment: Гениально! Всё заработало! Спасибо! ;) Не думал, что ещё и эту переменную необходимо указывать, много времени потратил на поиск информации и нашёл только здесь. Надеюсь, что это поможет и другим!))

Comment: На здоровье. Я, честно говоря, совсем не в теме вашй проблемы, я только гуглить умею хорошо. Потому будет неплохо, если вы решение оформите как ответ, раз оно вам помогло.

Comment: Ещё раз спасибо за помощь! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть ответ! Если кто-то столкнулся с подобной проблемой, то необходимо добавить новую системную переменную с именем «JRE_HOME» и указать точно такой же путь, как и для переменной «JAVA_HOME», если речь идёт о Java SE 14, хотя и с другими версиями тоже должно работать. То бишь, в моём случае было необходимо указать примерно следующее:

```
JRE_HOME: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14.0.1
```

За наводку премного благодарен камраду **tym32167**. Спасибо за помощь!